# Importing modules in python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, import

I am using python 3.5. 
I want to import some modules:

- One, with some constants, for example: 
  m.constant1 = 2,3 
  m.constant2 = 4,5
- Another one with some functions definitions, for example: 
  def b_initialize (model,i) :
  return m.binit

And the use this information in my main program,
how can I do it??

Thanks in advance,

Michael

Comment: Hi Michael, it would be helpful to clarify exactly what you mean, maybe by some code examples. This sounds a bit like a general python-related import question rather than a Pyomo-specific one.

Answer (score 0):

In the first lines of your program, write `import m`

and to access `constant1` and `constant2`, you can write `m.constant1` and `m.constant2`

Alternatively, in the beginning you can write `from m import constant1, constant2`. From then on, you can access the `constant1` and `constant2` just by writing their names, without the `m.`

As for the function definitions, I can't help you if I don't know the module name, but you if you do, just write `modulename.functionname`.

This is used very commonly and has most likely been asked and answered on the internet before, though, so make sure to search thoroughly before asking on Stack Overflow.